# When and where todo dependency injection.Could you clarify?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Getting more and more familiar with DI but I still have few niggles.

Read few articles where it says "Injection must be done at the entry point"

Suppose I have a situation where we have wcf Services and these are used both by internal win/web application and external third parties uses those wcf services.

Now where do you inject the Services and repositories?
Above to me seems to be a common scenarios!

Also i pass all those interfaces around.(Very good for mocking) how do I stop somebody from calling EG my repository from a layer that should **NOT** be calling the repository.

EG  only the business Layer should call DAL.
Now by injecting a IRepository into a controller nothing stops a developer from calling the DAL.

Any suggestion? Links that clear all this

Noddy example of my poor man DI. How do I do the same using unity and Injecting all at the entryPoint?

```
[TestFixture]
public class Class1
{
    [Test]
    public void GetAll_when_called_is_invoked()
    {
        var mockRepository = new Mock<ICustomerRepository>();
        mockRepository.Setup(x => x.GetAll()).Verifiable();

        new CustomerService(mockRepository.Object);
        ICustomerBiz customerBiz = new CustomerBizImp(mockRepository.Object);

        customerBiz.GetAll();
        mockRepository.Verify(x=>x.GetAll(),Times.AtLeastOnce());
    }
}
public class CustomerService : ICustomerService  //For brevity (in real will be a wcf service)
{
    private readonly ICustomerRepository _customerRepository;

    public CustomerService(ICustomerRepository customerRepository)
    {
        _customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAll()
    {
        return _customerRepository.GetAll();
    }
}

public class CustomerBizImp : ICustomerBiz
{
    private readonly ICustomerRepository _customerRepository;

    public CustomerBizImp(ICustomerRepository customerRepository)
    {
        _customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAll()
    {
        return _customerRepository.GetAll();
    }
}

public class CustomerRepository : ICustomerRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAll()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
public interface ICustomerRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Customer> GetAll();
}

public interface ICustomerService
{
    IEnumerable<Customer> GetAll();
}

public interface ICustomerBiz
{
    IEnumerable<Customer> GetAll();
}

public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

thanks

Comment: We used to do only a DEBUG based build DIs in our code. In other words production never used to have a DI based codes at all.

Comment: @zenwalker then you've wasted your time using DI, one of the best reasons to use it is so that you can inject deifferent modules for developing, testing and release, each module tested on its own.

Comment: Yep thats what i meant. We did DI only for testing purpose i.e DEBUG mode. We did not sent them as part of our production code i.e RELEASE mode to customer. Sorry if it was not clear earlier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a blog post on [Composition roots](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx) or what you call entry points. Its from Mark Seemann the author of [Dependency Injection in .NET](http://www.amazon.de/Dependency-Injection-NET-Mark-Seemann/dp/1935182501/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1325501551&sr=8-1). If you are looking for a deep understanding of DI this book is a must read.

There are a lot of samples out there on how to combine WCF and DI. If you are hosting your services in IIS you would need to write a custom *ServiceHostFactory* where you initialize you DI container. This is a sample for [Microsoft's Unity](http://www.neovolve.com/post/2010/05/15/Unity-dependency-injection-for-WCF-services-e28093-Part-1.aspx).

As to

> how do I stop somebody from calling EG my repository from a layer that should NOT be calling the repository

Do you use poor man's DI and pass all your references around through all your layers? Then you should definitely consider using a DI/IoC container like *StructureMap*, *Castle Windsor*, *AutoFac* or *Unity*.

If you are asking "how can I in general avoid the situation that someone does not follow my layer boundaries": Write tests that fail if an assembly references another one it should not reference (e.g. UI should not reference DAL).

---

**UPDATE**

I assume you wanted the service to use *ICustomerBiz* instead of the *ICustomerRepository*. If that is right the setup for *Unity* would look like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetAll_with_Unity()
{
  var container = new UnityContainer();
  container.RegisterType<ICustomerRepository, CustomerRepository>();
  container.RegisterType<ICustomerBiz, CustomerBizImp>();
  container.RegisterType<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();
  var svc = container.Resolve<ICustomerService>();
  var all = svc.GetAll();
  Assert.AreEqual(1, all.Count());
}
```

Comment: @Weber thanks for your reply and links. I had already read Mark Seeman posts  + I m now looking into writing a ServiceHostFactory.Poor Man's DI.Yes I am doing this. Is there an example of using Unity that shows how to avoid passing refs around? I am doing   UI --> (channelFactory)ServiceLayer(wcf) ---> BizLayer-->Dal. Only Biz Layer should call DAL.Injecting into constructor(passing around) IService and IRepository between layers

Comment: The [TecX project](http://tecx.codeplex.com) contains a [sample](http://tecx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20AutoMagic&referringTitle=Documentation) on how to inject a service using Unity.
Your view-model class would need a constructor that takes an _IMyService_ parameter. Then you tell Unity that _IMyService_ should be mapped using the _ChannelFactory_.
And on the service side your service implementation takes an _IMyBiz_ parameter and the business logic implementation takes an _IDal_. You need to tell Unity that _IMyBiz_ maps to _MyBizImpl_ and _IDal_ to _NHibernateDal_ and you are done.

Comment: @Weber thanks for the link.Digesting the link.What you describe is exactly what I want to do. Is there or come across a noddy example the goes from the beginning to end using unity and Interested in looking how the various project ref each other etc...

Comment: @Weber added noddy example of implementation.

Answer (score 0):

`DI` is much more about injecting a dependency inside your dipendency architecture, that's why it can not resolve, as is, layers isolation problem you face.

Production code can and *should* contain `DI` code, if it needed.

- If we are talking about `plugin-based` architecture`DI` is one of  most natural choices out there.
- if we are talking about app behaviour change, like for example `Logging` system choice: save on remote server if connection present if not injject local logger for future sync with the server.

There are plenty of usages of `DI` in production, but all that is up to `Architect` to decide *when*, *how* and *if* use it.

In other words, there is no single rule of it use, it's not a hummer for any nail, so use it where *you* think it's approriate and use it wisely.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.How do I prevent a repository to be called from a layer is not intended to when Dependency injection is used.Any examples anywhere?

Comment: @user231465: `repository` in domain model is a super class that has to be responsable for managing object in your dependency model and shouldn't present referencies inside injecting laters. Who is gonna cal your `repository`?

Comment: at what stage do you inject your "IRepositories".

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really understand your problem. The `repository` implements an interface. If consumer object csn not host *that* interface, there is no way it can get a reference to a `repositiry` it doesn't support. Isn't it?